# Objective-C: How to force a call to `+initialize` at startup rather than later when the class happens to used for the first time?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, startup

### Problem

For certain classes, I would like to explicitly call the `+initialize` method when my program starts, rather than allowing the runtime system to call it implicitly at some nondeterministic point later when the class happens to first be used. Problem is, this isn't recommended.

Most of my classes have little to no work to do in initialization, so I can just let the runtime system do its thing for those, but at least one of my classes requires as much as 1 second to initialize on older devices, and I don't want things to stutter later when the program is up and running. (A good example of this would be sound effects — I don't want sudden delay the first time I try to play a sound.)

What are some ways to do this initialization at startup-time?

### Attempted solutions

What I've done in the past is call the `+initialize` method manually from `main.c`, and made sure that every `+initialize` method has a `bool initialized` variable wrapped in a `@synchronized` block to prevent accidental double-initialization. But now Xcode is warning me that `+initialize` would be called twice. No surprise there, but I don't like ignoring warnings, so I'd rather fix the problem.

My next attempt (earlier today) was to define a `+preinitialize` function that I call directly instead `+initialize`, and to make sure I call `+preinitialize` implicitly inside of `+initialize` in case it is not called explicitly at startup. But the problem here is that something inside `+preinitialize` is causing `+initialize` to be called implicitly by the runtime system, which leads me to think that this is a very unwise approach.

So let's say I wanted to keep the actual initialization code inside `+initialize` (where it's really intended to be) and just write a tiny dummy method called `+preinitialize` that forces `+initialize` to be called implicitly by the runtime system somehow? Is there a standard approach to this? In a unit test, I wrote...

```
+ (void) preinitialize
{
  id dummy = [self alloc];
  NSLog(@"Preinitialized: %i", !!dummy);
}
```

...but in the debugger, I did not observe `+initialize` being called prior to `+alloc`, indicating that `+initialize` was not called implicitly by the runtime system inside of `+preinitialize`.

### Edit

I found a really simple solution, and posted it as an answer.

Comment: *why* are you trying to do everything static? Why don't you just use a `SoundManager`, create an instance at launch, call `doStartupStuff` on it and move on - you are making your life A LOT harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @luk2302 — Audio is just one example. I have other things like pseudorandom number generator initialization, prime number library initialization (does memory mapping and other things), and preloading of small, frequently used images. I want these initializers all to be called before anything else and, in some cases, to be called in a certain predeterministic order, as there are dependencies.

Comment: if you want it to happen in a deterministic order, call it in that deterministic order. I cannot think of a single reason why you would want to make it that much harder by introducing static stuff. You know what you need, then take care of setting up that by *explicitly* calling the needed function. I do have no idea whatsoever what init shenanigans you are trying to create here. But I am 95% certain you should not do it. But you can still wait for someone to answer your question - while I doubt that is going to happen.

Comment: @luk2302 — There are no shenanigans here. The problem is that you can't call `+initialize` explicitly from outside the class (to force initialization to occur at startup rather than at some random point later) without getting a compiler warning about `+initialize` being called twice. I mean, I could disable that warning, but I don't want to be disabling warnings.

Comment: @luk2302 — I found a super simple solution (and posted it as an answer). Basically, all one needs to do is to define `+initialize` as normal, and in the startup code, call any method in the class and throw away the return value.

Comment: I have seen that answer yesterday already and have still no idea why you have to *anything* implicitly. All given answers (including yours) boil down to exactly what I said in the comments: **call some method that does the setup**, does not matter what name you give it or if it has a special meaning in the class loading process, define it and call it.

Comment: @luk2302 — Well, I don't *have to* cajole `+initialize` into being called implicitly; it would work to define, say, `+actual_initialize` and call this from the startup code as well as from `+initialize`. But it seems much cleaner to me to use the standard initializer and simply provide the option to execute that standard initializer early (instead of as late as possible). This way, the client code decides when to execute the initializer. Some client code wants to invoke the initializers immediately upon startup; other client code doesn't care, and allows the intiailizers to be invoked lazily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It turns out that the solution is embarrassingly simple.

I had been operating under the mistaken belief that `+initialize` would not be called until the first instance method in a class is invoked. This is not so. It is called before the first instance method *or* class method is invoked (other than `+load`, of course).

So the solution is simply to cause `+initialize` to be invoked implicitly. There are multiple ways to do this. Two are discussed below.

### Option 1 (simple and direct, but unclear)

In startup code, simply call some method (e.g., `+class`) of the class you want to initialize at startup, and discard the return value:

```
(void)[MyClass class];
```

This is guaranteed by the Objective-C runtime system to call `[MyClass initialize]` implicitly if it has not yet been called.

### Option 2 (less direct, but clearer)

Create a `+preinitialize` method with an empty body:

```
+ (void) preinitialize
{
  // Simply by calling this function at startup, an implicit call to
  // +initialize is generated.
}
```

Calling this function at startup implicitly invokes `+initialize`:

```
[MyClass preinitialize];  // Implicitly invokes +initialize.
```

This `+preinitialize` method serves no purpose other than to document the intention. Thus, it plays well with `+initialize` and `+deinitialize` and is fairly self-evident in the calling code. I write a `+deinitialize` method for every class I write that has an `+initialize` method. `+deinitialize` is called from the shutdown code; `+initialize` is called implicitly via `+preinitialize` in the startup code. Super simple. Sometimes I also write a `+reinitialize` method, but the need for this is rare.

I am now using this approach for all my class initializers. Instead of calling `[MyClass initialize]` in the start up code, I am now calling `[MyClass preinitialize]`. It's working great, and the call stack shown in the debugger confirms that `+initialize` is being called exactly at the intended time and fully deterministically.

Answer (score 4):

The first possible place to run class-specific code is [`+load`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load), which happens when the class is added to the ObjC runtime. It's still not completely deterministic which classes' `+load` implementations will be called in what order, but there are some rules. From the docs:

> The order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. All initializers in any framework you link to.
> 2. All `+load` methods in your image.
> 3. All C++ static initializers and C/C++ `__attribute__(constructor)`
>      functions in your image.
> 4. All initializers in frameworks that link to you.
>
> In addition:
>
> - A class’s `+load` method is called after all of its superclasses’ `+load`
>     methods.
> - A category `+load` method is called after the class’s own `+load` method.

So, two peer classes (say, both direct `NSObject` subclasses) will both `+load` in step 2 above, but there's no guarantee which order the two of them will be relative to each other.

Because of that, and because metaclass objects in ObjC are generally not great places to set and maintain state, you might want something else...

#### A better solution?

For example, your "global" state can be kept in the (single) instance of a singleton class. Clients can call `[MySingletonClass sharedSingleton]` to get that instance and not care about whether it's getting its initial setup done at that time or earlier. And if a client needs to make sure it happens earlier (and in a deterministic order relative to other things), they can call that method at a time of their choosing — such as in `main` before kicking off the `NSApplication`/`UIApplication` run loop.

#### Alternatives

If you don't want this costly initialization work to happen at app startup, and you don't want it to happen when the class is being put to use, you have a few other options, too.

- Keep the code in `+initialize`, and contrive to make sure the class gets messaged before its first "real" use. Perhaps you can kick off a background thread to create and initialize a dummy instance of that class from `application:didFinishLaunching:`, for example.
- Put that code someplace else — in the class object or in a singleton, but in a method of your own creation regardless — and call it directly at a time late enough for setup to avoid slowing down app launch but soon enough for it to be done before your class' "real" work is needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! Turns out I found a really simple and deterministic solution — as you say, make sure the class gets messaged before its first "real" use. I posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here. First, you should never call `+initialize` directly. Second, if you have some piece of initialization that can take over a second, you generally shouldn't run it on the main queue because that would hang the whole program.

Put your initialization logic into a separate method so you can call it when you expect to. Optionally, put the logic into a `dispatch_once` block so that it's safe to call it multiple times. Consider the following example.

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
+ (void)setup;
@end

@implementation Foo

+ (void)setup {
    NSLog(@"Setup start");

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"Setup running");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; // Expensive op
    });
}
@end
```

Now in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` call it in the background.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"START");

    // Here, you should setup your UI into an "inactive" state, since we can't do things until
    // we're done initializing.

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [Foo setup];
        // And any other things that need to intialize in order.
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"We're all ready to go now! Turn on the the UI. Set the variables. Do the thing.");
    });
    return YES;
}
```

This is how you want to approach things if order matters to you. All the runtime options (`+initialize` and `+load`) make no promises on order, so don't rely on them for work that needs that. You'll just make everything much more complicated than it needs to be.

You may want to be able to check for programming errors in which you accidentally call `Foo` methods before initialization is done. That's best done, IMO, with assertions. For example, create an `+isInitialized` method that checks whatever `+setup` does (or create a class variable to track it). Then you can do this:

```
#if !defined(NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS)
#define FooAssertInitialized(condition) NSAssert([Foo isInitialized], @"You must call +setup before using Foo.")
#else
#define FooAssertInitialized(condition)
#endif

- (void)someMethodThatRequiresInitialization {
    FooAssertInitialized();

    // Do stuff
}
```

This makes it easy to mark methods that really do require initialization before use vs ones that may not.

Comment: Cool...these are helpful suggestions! However, I found a simpler solution and posted it as an answer. I had been under the mistaken belief that `+initialize` would only be called automatically when the first instance method of a class is called, when actually it is called when the first *instance method or class method* of the class is called.

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa provides a setup point earlier than `+initialize` in the form of [`+load`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load), which is called very shortly after the program's start. This is a weird environment: other classes that rely on `+load` may not be completely initialized yet, and more importantly, your `main()` [has not been called](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load)! That means there's no autorelease pool in place.

After `load` but before `initialize`, functions marked with `__attribute__((constructor))` will be called. This doesn't allow you to do much that you can't do in `main()` so far as I know.

One option would be to create a dummy instance of your class in either `main()` or a constructor, guaranteeing that `initialize` will be called as early as possible.